# Logstash not printing anything

Tags: logstash

I am using logstash for the first time and trying to setup a simple pipeline for just printing the nginx logs. Below is my config file

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/nginx/*access*"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I have saved the file as `/opt/logstash/nginx_simple.conf`

And trying to execute the following command

```
sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /opt/logstash/nginx_simple.conf
```

However the only output I can see is:

```
Logstash startup completed
Logstash shutdown completed
```

The file is not empty for sure. As per my understanding I should be seeing the output on my console. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you appending stuff to the file?

Comment: Not at the moment. Does it not fetch the existing stuff from the file? If it does not, then how can I keep it alive so that it does not shutdown immediately after starting ?

Comment: If you start it from the command line, it should just keep running until you kill it.  If it's dying before then, check /var/log/logstash/*

Comment: I'm curious if there is a Logstash forwarder that's causing this issue.

Comment: surprisingly everything is working fine when I use my full fledged pipeline with filters and output to elasticsearch

Comment: Please add --debug as parameter and tell us what you get

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code as your Logstash configuration, in order to setup a simple pipeline for just printing the nginx logs.

```
 input {
     file {
         path => "/var/log/nginx/*.log"
         type => "nginx"
         start_position => "beginning"
         sincedb_path=> "/dev/null"
     }
 }

 filter {
   if [type] == "nginx" {
     grok {
       patterns_dir => "/home/krishna/Downloads/logstash-2.1.0/pattern"
       match => { 
         "message" => "%{NGINX_LOGPATTERN:data}"
       }
     }
   }
   date {
     match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
     }
 }

 output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9200" ]
   }

   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the character encoding of your logfile is UTF-8. If it is not, try to change it and restart the Logstash.